# ASP.net MVC dropdownlist with inactive items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm having a problem with my application. 
I have a table "Files" witch has a relationship with a table called "Transactioncodes".

```
public class File
    {
        [Display(Name = "EcommerceFile_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "EcommerceFile_FileNumber", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        public string FileNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "EcommerceFile_TransactionCode", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        public int? TransactionCodeId { get; set; }
        public virtual TransactionCode TransactionCode { get; set; }

        ....
    }

public class TransactionCode
    {

        [Display(Name = "TransactionCode_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "TransactionCode_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "TransactionCode_Active", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

    }
```

When creating a file, the user should select a transactioncode for this file. Offcourse this isnt a problem. 
Then when the user opens the file information everything should be shown and it should also be possible to edit the information.

But it should be possible for administrators to deactivate transactioncodes (and also add new transactioncodes). The deactivated transactioncodes dont show up in the dropdown lists so they cant be chosen anymore (this is exactly what i intended).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TransactionCodeId, new SelectList(ViewBag.transactioncodes, "Id", "Name", Model.TransactionCodeId), "", ViewBag.disableControls == true ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" } : new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But the problem is that when a already existing file is opened (which has a deactivated transactioncode) the transactioncode field is empty (because the value is not available in the dropdownlist since it is inactive).

I hope somebody over here have had a similar problem and knows a way to solve it.

Please advise.

Comment: How do you want your app to behave in that case? Show the transaction code, but disable? Or force user to choose an active code instead? Or anything else?

Comment: When it is already selected the user should only be able to see the value or change the value (to an active item). Files created (when the transactioncode was still active) should always keep the value (even if the transactioncode is now deactivated). This is to keep the integrety of the old files.